# Spring Security 6 - unable to set up redirection to Keycloak logout endpoint

Tags: spring-boot, keycloak

I try to implement in Spring Boot + Keycloak implementation of Oath 2.0.

Spring boot 3 + Spring Security 6.

When I try to  do backend-channel logout calling /logout endpoint of my spring boot application **it doesn't redirect** to keycloak logout endpoint.

In browser it looks like - no chance to escape ((

I check my security filter chain in debug and understand that **LogoutFilter** call before **any Aunthentication kind filters**.
So in internal code of LogoutFilter it is no chance to get populated Authentication object and next extract issuer provider URI  .

**My Source Code**

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity(debug = true)
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class SecurityConfig {

    private final CustomJwtTokenConverter customJwtTokenConverter;

     @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .sessionManagement(session -> session
                        .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                )
                .formLogin(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
                .rememberMe(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
                .httpBasic(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
                .csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
                .cors(Customizer.withDefaults())
                
                .oauth2Login(oauth -> oauth
                        .authorizationEndpoint(conf -> conf
                                .authorizationRedirectStrategy(redirectStrategy())
                        )
                )
                .oauth2Client(Customizer.withDefaults())
                .authorizeHttpRequests(authorize -> authorize
                        .requestMatchers(AUTH_WHITELIST).permitAll()
                        .anyRequest().authenticated()
                )
                .oauth2ResourceServer(oauth -> oauth
                        .jwt(jwt -> jwt
                                .jwtAuthenticationConverter(customJwtTokenConverter)
                        )
                )
       
                .logout(logout -> logout
                        .addLogoutHandler(keycloakLogoutHandler)
                        .logoutSuccessHandler(oidcLogoutSuccessHandler(clientRegistrationRepository)))
        ;
        return http.build();
    }

    @Bean
    OidcClientInitiatedLogoutSuccessHandler oidcLogoutSuccessHandler(ClientRegistrationRepository clientRegistrationRepository) {
        OidcClientInitiatedLogoutSuccessHandler successHandler = new OidcClientInitiatedLogoutSuccessHandler(clientRegistrationRepository);
        successHandler.setPostLogoutRedirectUri("/api");
        return successHandler;
    }



}
```

**Debug Output of my security filter chain :**

```
Security filter chain: [
  DisableEncodeUrlFilter
  WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter
  SecurityContextHolderFilter
  HeaderWriterFilter
  CorsFilter
  LogoutFilter
  OAuth2AuthorizationRequestRedirectFilter
  OAuth2AuthorizationRequestRedirectFilter
  OAuth2LoginAuthenticationFilter
  DefaultLoginPageGeneratingFilter
  DefaultLogoutPageGeneratingFilter
  BearerTokenAuthenticationFilter
  RequestCacheAwareFilter
  SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter
  AnonymousAuthenticationFilter
  OAuth2AuthorizationCodeGrantFilter
  SessionManagementFilter
  ExceptionTranslationFilter
  AuthorizationFilter
]
```

What is most compact and understanable way to set up security chain to do next ? :
1)Logged In User push logout button
2) Browser send request to boot /logout endpoint - after that boot redirect request to keycloak logout endpoint with post_redirect_uri and id_token_hint request params - > user logout happens in keycloak and user redirected to keycloak login page.

In simple words I want that my code works as here https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-keycloak - VIA custom KeycloakLogoutHandler class.But when I try to repeat this in my source code - I get Nullpointer Exception because of there is no Authentication Object during LogoutFilter stage.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do doesn't conform to any standard.

The [OpenID Connect Back-Channel Logout](https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-backchannel-1_0.html) is for OPs to notify RPs of the logout. Ie. you logout of Keycloak and it does a back channel logout of your application. Spring Security only just incorporated this feature in 6.2.0-M3 so it will be in 6.2.0 when it releases.

If you don't want the `OidcClientInitiatedLogoutSuccessHandler` to redirect the browser you can modify the redirect strategy to use a web client to call it similar to what you are doing in the `KeycloakLogoutHandler` and remove the custom handler.

Comment: I tried as you suggest. Next I check  devtools and it is no one request sent to keycloak logout endpoint.

Answer (score 0):

You are configuring your session management as stateless. This is typically only done for resource servers where the client is another server and not a browser user agent. Such resource servers would not have `oauth2Login` configured. Those servers will maintain the authentication to the resource server by always passing a bearer token.

Here as there is no session for the browser, typically using a http only cookie, it is somewhat expected that the user isn't authenticated when you hit the logout endpoint.

You should remove the session management configuration. Also there is duplication of logic with your custom logout handler and the `OidcClientInitiatedLogoutSuccessHandler` so you should choose one or the other.